# Не находит файл

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, path

No such file or directory: 'IMG_20211227_220859.jpg'
listdir вроде бы выдает нужный список файлов, а random.choice выбирает один, но не пойму почему не находит, не там ищет? Вроде бы он должен полностью путь указывать в ошибке, но показывает одно имя файла. Помогите пожалуйста, головой бьюсь уже второй час.

```
if call.data == 'foto':
 img_list = os.listdir(configure.config['path'])    
 img_otvet = random.choice(img_list)
 bot.send_photo(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, photo=open(img_otvet, 'rb' ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

listdir выдаёт только имена файлов. Надо имя соединить с путем к папке:

```
img_otvet = os.path.join(configure.config['path'], random.choice(img_list))
```